# Remove stopwords from set of files

Tags: python

I am trying to read in all of the files in a directory, access a file with stopwords, go through each file, remove the stopwords from each file, and then generate a copy of all of the files with the stopwords removed. I am able to read in all of the files and also print them as an array, but I get stuck when it comes to two steps: removing the stop words, and printing the resulting files onto a new set of files. The last three lines of code are an example for generating just one text file, but I need some kind of loop to generate them all.

```
import pathlib

stop_words = open("StopWordList.txt")
stop_words.read()

for path in pathlib.Path(r'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\HelloWorld\emails').iterdir():
    if path.is_file():
        current_file = open(path, "r")
        lines = current_file.read()
        words = lines.split()

        for y in stop_words:
            if not y in stop_words:

                appendFile = open('filteredtext.txt', 'a')
                appendFile.write(" "+y)
                appendFile.close()
```

Comment: refer this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/removing-stop-words-nltk-python/  i believe this is what you might want

Comment: you get `y` from `stop_words` and later check if `y` is in `stop_words` ? It makes no sense. You should get `y` from `words`

Comment: maybe you should get `words`, use it to create new list without `stopwords`, and later concatenate all words to one string and then save this string to file. It may works faster then writing every word separatelly.

Comment: BTW: what if there is some char at the end of word - `.`, `,`, `!`, `?`. You have to remove it before checking it with stopworkds. And you should also compare lower cases. Maybe you should use module `nltk` for this.

Comment: you should use `path` to generate new name for results instead of `'filteredtext.txt'`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it (I don't have file with stopwords) but I would do

```
import pathlib
import sys


if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    folder = sys.argv[1] # get folder as parameter
else:
    folder = r'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\HelloWorld\emails'


stop_words = open("StopWordList.txt").read().lower()  # to compare lowercase stopwords with lowercase words

for path in pathlib.Path(folder).iterdir():
    if path.is_file():

        # --- read all text at once ---

        input_file = open(path) #  it use `r` as default
        text = input_file.read()
        input_file.close()

        original_words = text.split()  # text -> words

        # --- remove stopwords ---

        filtered_words = []

        for word in original_words:
            temp_word = word.lower().rstrip('.,!?')
            if temp_word not in stop_words:   # check lowercase without `.,!?`
                filtered_words.appeend(word)  # keep original word

        # --- save all text at once ---

        output_path = path + '-filtered'  # create new filename

        text = " ".join(filtered_words)  # words -> text

        output_file = open('output_path', 'w')
        output_file.write(text)
        output_file.close()
```

It doesn't removes `.,!?` and doesn't convert to lowercase.

Eventually you could split code to functions

```
import pathlib
import sys

# --- functions ---

def read_words(path):

    input_file = open(path) #  it use `r` as default
    text = input_file.read()
    input_file.close()

    words = text.split()  # text -> words

    return words

def filter_words(words, stopwords):

    filtered_words = []

    for word in all_words:
        temp_word = word.lower().rstrip('.,!?')
        if temp_word not in stop_words:
            filtered_words.appeend(word)

    return filtered_words

def write_words(path, words):

    text = " ".join(words)  # words -> text

    output_file = open(path, 'w')
    output_file.write(text)
    output_file.close()

# --- main ---

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    folder = sys.argv[1] # get folder as parameter
else:
    folder = r'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\HelloWorld\emails'

stop_words = open("StopWordList.txt").read().lower()  # to compare lowercase stopwords with lowercase words

for path in pathlib.Path(folder).iterdir():
    if path.is_file():
        words = read_words(path)
        words = fiter_words(words, stopwords)
        write_words(path + '-fitered', words)
```

Comment: you can get the stopwords from nltk package like this from nltk.corpus import stopwords  and getenglish stopwords like this stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

Comment: @SachinRajput I know `nltk` (and probably I have it even installed) but I'm too lazy to test this code :)

Answer (score 0):

The follwoing code -which is based on your code- my help you, I have changed the names of some vaiables of your original code to be more meaningfull, in addition to some modifications:

```
import os
import pathlib

# preparing the StopWordList to be used with each file
stop_words = open("StopWordList.txt")
StopWordList_raw = stop_words.read()
stop_words.close()

StopWordList = StopWordList_raw.split()

# Pathes of source files and that for after-modifications
files_path = 'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\HelloWorld\emails'
# another folder, your should create first to store files after modifications in
files_after_path = 'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\HelloWorld\emails2'

for path in pathlib.Path(files_path).iterdir():
    if path.is_file():
        current_file = open(path, "r")
        # get the all contents of the file
        original_file_content = current_file.read()

        # get a copy for modifications if stop words exist
        file_content_after = original_file_content

        # remove stop words by replacing each of them with '' - if exist
        for w in StopWordList:
            file_content_after = file_content_after.replace(w, '')

        # if modifications done to the original content, save the file in the atrget path
        if original_file_content != file_content_after:
            file_name_after = os.path.join(files_after_path, path.name)
            print(file_name_after)
            TargetFile = open(file_name_after, 'w')
            TargetFile.write(file_content_after)
            TargetFile.close()
```